# Digester: Extracting node name

Tags: java, xml, apache

Is it possible to extract the node name using apache digester?

So, if the xml looks like

```
   <furniture>
     <sofa>
       .....
     </sofa>
     <coffeeTable>
       .....
     </coffeeTable>
   </furniture>
```

is it possible to extract the node name "sofa", "coffeeTable"?

I know it is possible using xpath but is it possible using digester?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(original answer)

Create a `Digester` for pattern `"furniture/*"` with a simple `Rule` that takes the second parameter to each call to the begin method and sticks it in a collection of your choice (a list to get all of them, a set to get only all unique names).

(edit)

Scratch that, it's a bit more complicated.

This works:

```
public class App 
{
    final static Rule printRule = new Rule() {
        public void begin(String namespace, String name,
                Attributes attributes) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }; 
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, SAXException
    {
        InputStream instr = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.xml");
        Digester dig = new Digester();
        dig.setRules(new RulesBase(){
            public List<Rule> match(String namespaceURI, String pattern) {
                return Arrays.asList(printRule);
            }
        });
        dig.parse(instr);
    }
}
```

This particular sample will print all element names including the root `furniture` element. I'll leave it to you to adjust the `match()` method to your needs.

Comment: Sweet, thank you.

I used a slight variation of what you proposed as I know the union of all furniture.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of matching that `ExtendedBaseRules` afford.

Let's say this is the content of `furniture.xml`:

```
<furniture>
   <sofa>
      <blah/>
   </sofa>
   <coffeeTable>
      <bleh/>
   </coffeeTable>
</furniture>
```

Let's say you want to get the element names of the direct children of `furniture` element. This is what `furniture/?` matches in the `ExtendedBaseRules`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.digester.*;

public class FurnitureDigest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("furniture.xml");
        Digester digester = new Digester();
        digester.setRules(new ExtendedBaseRules());
        final List<String> furnitures = new ArrayList<String>();
        digester.addRule("furniture/?", new Rule() {
            @Override public void end(String nspace, String name) {
                furnitures.add(name);
            }
        });
        digester.parse(file);
        System.out.println(furnitures); // prints "[sofa, coffeeTable]"
    }
}
```

#### API links

- [Package `org.apache.commons.digester`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/package-summary.html)
- [`org.apache.commons.digester.Rule`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/Rule.html)
- [`org.apache.commons.digester.ExtendedBaseRules`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/ExtendedBaseRules.html)