# Digester: Extracting node name for a map<tagname, value>

Tags: java, smartgwt, apache-commons-digester

My question is close to this one: [Digester: Extracting node name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165168/digester-extracting-node-name)

Even with the answer, I can't find out.

Here is my xml file (from smartgwt RestDataSource POST):

```
<data>
  <isc_OID_14>
    <attribute1>value1</attribute1>
    <attribute2>value2</attribute2>
  </isc_OID_14>
</data>
```

I would like to create, with Commons Digester, the following map :
{attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2}

I already have those lines:

```
digester = new Digester();
digester.addObjectCreate("data", HashMap.class);
// some "put" rules matching something like data/*
return digester.parse(myFile);
```

I do not know the list nor the name of tags in the `<data><sourceId /></data>`. `isc_OID_14` or `attribute1` can be named foobar or id or attribute335...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.digester.*;

public class DigestToMap {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("digestme.xml");
        Digester digester = new Digester();
        digester.setRules(new ExtendedBaseRules());
        digester.addObjectCreate("data", HashMap.class);
        digester.addRule("data/?", new Rule() {
            @Override public void end(String nspace, String name) {
                ((HashMap<String,String>)getDigester().peek()).put("[ID]", name);
            }
        });
        digester.addRule("*", new Rule() {
            @Override public void body(String nspace, String name, String text) {
                ((HashMap<String,String>)getDigester().peek()).put(name, text);
            }
        });
        Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>) digester.parse(file);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Basically it uses `ExtendedBaseRules` for the wildcard matching.

There are 3 rules:

- On `data`, `ObjectCreate` a `HashMap`
- On `data/?` (direct child of data), map `[ID]=name` (make this `Rule` a no-op if not needed)
- On `*` (everything else), map `name=text`

On my machine, this prints:

```
{[ID]=isc_OID_14, attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2}
```

#### API links

- [Package `org.apache.commons.digester`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/package-summary.html)
- [`org.apache.commons.digester.Rule`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/Rule.html)
- [`org.apache.commons.digester.ExtendedBaseRules`](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/ExtendedBaseRules.html)